# Turn .pyw Python-script to batch process

Tags: python, batch-processing

I've got an existing .pyw-script (with a GUI) and want to turn it into a batch process.

The script itselfs covert me a PDF to a new PDF
(for backup), but it's a bit annoying because I only can process 1 file at once.

Here are the inputs:

- Input-Filepath
- Output-Filepath

Is there now a way, so I can add a folder-path and it will convert all the existing files inside?

Comment: Sorry, it runs on Mac OSX Mavericks with Python 2.7

Comment: Use a regular shell script to automate the process.

Answer (score 0):

You could automate it using your favourite console script. I like bash:

The scripts are untested!

A version that expects: `<thescript> inputfile1 inputfile2 ... inputfileN` and outputs `inputfileN_out.pdf`

```
for ((i = 1; i < $#; ++i)); do
  inputfile="${!i}"
  outputfile="${inputfile}_out.pdf"
  <your python file> "$inputfile" "$outputfile"
done
```

And here is a version that takes a folder and processes all `pdf` files found and outputs `pdffilename_out.pdf`

```
while read -d$'\0' -r inputfile; do
  outputfile="${inputfile}_out.pdf"
   <your python file> "$inputfile" "$outputfile"
done < <(find "$1" -type f -iname '*.pdf' -print0)
```

Comment: Thank you for the super fast response! Oh bash, something new for me!
I changed your template ad #!/bin/bash to the first line and run it!
In the terminal i run -> bash pdfconvert.sh /User/Documents/PDF
but nothing happens, what did I wrong?